# Running regex from windows BATCH

Tags: regex, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to use regex running from a batch

```
<zed>(.*?)<zed>
```

to find values I've stored in a file

```
<process>34593845387<process>
<zed>M567<zed>
<encode>UTF16<encode>
```

I'm able to do that from java not from batch

Comment: Windows batch/cmd has no built-in facility for handling regex. You'll need to get another command-line utility and call it from your batch file, or use a different method altogether (like Powershell).

Comment: Not true, findstr supports regex

Comment: install [ACK](https://beyondgrep.com/install/)

Comment: @Richard - the version of regex that findstr supports is extremely rudimentary and can barely be considered regex. Additionally, batch has no good way of parsing XML, but if your data file looks _exactly_ like that, this can be solved with a one-liner.

Comment: @Noomak if my answer below helped, please accept it :)

Comment: The values appear to be invalid XML. Shouldn't your values look like `<zed>M567</zed>` ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to use something like powershell, or another tool.  The basics of what you can get in batch won't be enough.  Once you do, you'll probably want a regex like:

```
<zed>([^<]+)<
```

That way if later the format changes a bit from:

```
<zed>234<zed>
```

to

```
<zed>234< /zed>
```

or something, it will still work.  It's happened to me before :)

Answer (score 0):

`Findstr` can technically use regex, but it's limited to character sets and can't handle capturing.

If your data looks *exactly* like that (nothing to the left of `<zed>`), you can tokenize the string using `<` and `>` as delimiters and store the value of `<zed>` as the second token in the string.

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=<>" %%A in (data.txt) do if "%%A"=="zed" set zed_value=%%B"
```

You can then access the variable with `%zed_value%`. If you have multiple `<zed>` fields, the variable will contain the value of the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `cscript` to access use Javascript regex?

```sh
type data.txt | cscript //nologo match.js "<zed>(.*)<zed>"
```

Where `match.js` is defined as:

```js
if (WScript.Arguments.Count() !== 1) {
  WScript.Echo("Syntax: match.js regex");
  WScript.Quit(1);
}
var rx = new RegExp(WScript.Arguments(0), "i");
var matched = false;
while (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) {
  var str = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
  if (str.match(rx)) {
    WScript.Echo(str);
    matched = true;
  }
}
if (!matched) {
  WScript.Quit(1);
}
```